# Не получается эффект меню с jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

Есть код  JS:

```
$('#navigationa li').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true).animate({height:'60px'}, 500, 'easeOutBounce')  
    },
    function(){
        $(this).stop(true).animate({height:'20px'}, 500, 'easeOutCirc')
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="navigationa">
    <li><a href="#">go go go1</a><img id='lol' src="img/kiska.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href="#">go go go2</a><img id='lol' src="img/kiska.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href="#">go go go3</a><img id='lol' src="img/kiska.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><a href="#">go go go4</a><img id='lol' src="img/kiska.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Нужно что бы при наведении на `#navigationa li` картинка появлялась с блоком.А у меня она сразу видна. Уже 4 часа ломаю голову. Подскажите как сделать или направьте на правильное решение. Спасибо !

ВОТ ССЫЛКА НА ПРИМЕР ! http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/3/

Comment: Вот вы ломаете голову над кодом, а я уже несколько минут ломаю голову над вашим вопросом )) Ничо не понятно. Сформулируйте задачу как-то более понятным языком и не плохо бы выложить код на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). И не только html + js, но и css тоже б не помешало.

Comment: У img выставьте в css display: none, а при наведении на { #navigation li } с помощью jQuery выставляйте display: block;

Comment: зачем тут jQuery и animate? CSS вам на что? Псевдоселектор :hover для кого? Кому придумали transition?

Comment: вот так у вас не будет работать $('#navigationa li'), а вот так может $('#navigationa li а') но только с первым элементом. Но чтоб все сработала нужно добавить атрибут data="".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем правило:

```
#navigationa li{
    /* ... */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

И подкорректируем картинки

```
#navigationa li img {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;        
}
```

И вот то, [что имеем на выходе](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ad8zr/4/). Надо же было столько мучаться? Сразу бы выложили код - быстрее бы ответ получили. ))